# Parsing Python arguments

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to cover the following 4 scenarios:

1. No parameters
2. DB param
3. DB param and 1 option
4. No DB param and 1 option

So far I have the program working for all scenarios. However, I'm not happy with the way it's implemented. Is it possible to change this to a cleaner solution, rather than checking if there's only 1 parameter passed or catching an exception?

```
def do_work(database=None):
    if database:
        print 'Doing work for {0}'.format(database)
    else:
        print 'Doing work all database'

def do_other_work(database=None):
    if database:
        print 'Doing other work for {0}'.format(database)
    else:
        print 'Doing other work all database'

def create_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Parser')
    parser.add_argument('--db', '-d', dest='database',
                        default=None, required=False, help='Database name')

    option_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
    option_group.add_argument('-a', dest='cmd',
                              action='store_const',
                              const=lambda args: do_other_work(args.database)
    return parser

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    do_work()

parser = create_parser()
parsed_args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

try:
    parsed_args.cmd(parsed_args)
except TypeError:
    do_work(parsed_args.database)
```

- No parameters passed: `do_work()` for all databases
- `db` parameter passed and no option: `do_work()` for just that database
- `db` parameter and an option: `do_other_work()` just for that database
- No `db` parameter and an option: `do_other_work()` for all databases

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You do not have to check `len(sys.argv)` yourself. A properly constructed `ArgumentParser` will sort that out by itself.
- Likewise, you do not need to pass `sys.argv[1:]` to `parse_args()`, `argparse` will figure it out.
- `default=None` and `required=False` are default values for an optional argument (those starting with `'-'`), you do not need to supply them.
- You do not need to use a `lambda` to specify the function to call, just pass in the name of the function: it will simplify handling this parameters.
- You can add `do_work` as a default value for `'-a'`: no more `TypeError` as the content of `parsed_args.cmd` will alway be a callable.
- There is no need in using a mutually exclusive group if you only ever put one option in it: remove it.
- You should use [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029) and put your top-level code under it.
- In `do_*work` you should test `database` using `is None` or `is not None`.

```
def do_work(database=None):
    if database is not None:
        print 'Doing work for {0}'.format(database)
    else:
        print 'Doing work all database'

def do_other_work(database=None):
    if database is not None:
        print 'Doing other work for {0}'.format(database)
    else:
        print 'Doing other work all database'

def create_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Parser')
    parser.add_argument('--db', '-d', dest='database', help='Database name')
    parser.add_argument('-a', dest='cmd', action='store_const',
                        const=do_other_work, default=do_work)
    return parser


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parsed_args = create_parser().parse_args()
    parserd_args.cmd(parsed_args.database)
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for the input. The mutually exclusive group is in fact a multiple option group. I just removed the other options for the sake of the post. Is it possible to use this default=do_work option for all mutually exclusive items and go there if there's no mutually exclusive parameter passed ?

Comment: I knew I should have voted to close this post as off-topic for hypothetical code. If you want advices on your real code, post your real code…

Comment: The real code doesn't belong to me. This is a short, working snippet creating the exact same scenario in a generic form.

Comment: Which isn't since the group had more arguments than what you showed us. Anyway, `option_group.set_defaults(cmd=do_work)` should do the job.